# Jquery ajax post to php but is saying no value in variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am working on an instant search thing and when I submit the form search-form it is going to make an ajax post to PHP. It sends and everything but then the PHP page says that the variable has no value but the data is clearly being posted.

```
        $('#search-form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Search.php",
                cache: false,
                data: $("#search-form").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert($("#search-form").serialize());
                    $("#searched").fadeIn("fast");
                    $("#results").empty();
                    $("#results").append(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Your js looks fine, post your php

Comment: what did you get in print_r($_POST); in your php file?

Comment: array (size=1)
  'search-priddly' => string 'kenny' (length=5) thats what print_r($_POST) did the search file is pretty big but it just goes like: if(isset($_POST['search-priddly'])){$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search-priddly']); mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = '$search'");}else{}

Comment: please make console.log(data) in your success function and look what the callback get's, i think the response is an array at this moment so you can't append it directly (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a console opened up in your browser, Firefox: bugzilla, Chrome and IE have a built-in.  It shows you what is happening in asynchronous requests.

in your php file at the top do this:

```
var_dump($_POST);

//OR DO THIS:
// print_r($_POST);
```

Then look at your browser console to see what the response is.  It should spit out an array.  and you can see what the name of your data is.  This is the quickest way to debug any ajax request.

Also, don't forget that you serialized the data with .serialize();

Comment: In your browser console, there should be a params tab.  it will show you what was sent.  If it only shows one param it is because you serialized the data.  So you need to unserialize it.

Comment: chrome says XHR finished loading: "http://127.0.0.1/Search.php". jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
send jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.10.2.js:8136
(anonymous function) Home.php?page=Board.php:114
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.10.2.js:5095
elemData.handle